# AngularJS Directive Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I want to build a directive that allows me to use a twitter bootstrap component in one tag:

The tag looks like this:

```
                <bootstrapinput
                    model="lastName"
                    key="lastName"
                    localized="Surname"
                    formpath="playerForm.lastName"
                    required>
                 </bootstrapinput>
```

The directive looks like this

```
 .directive('bootstrapinput', function () {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        compile:function (tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
            var type = tAttrs.type || 'text';
            var required = tAttrs.hasOwnProperty('required') ? 'required' : '';
            var ngClazz = tAttrs.hasOwnProperty('formpath') ? 'ng-class="{error: ' + tAttrs.formpath + '.$invalid}"' : '';
            var html = '<div class="control-group" ' + ngClazz + '>' +
                '<label class="control-label" for="' + tAttrs.key + '">' + tAttrs.localized + '</label>' +
                '<div class="controls">' +
                '<input ng-model="'+tAttrs.model+'" type="' + type + '" id="' + tAttrs.key + '" name="' + tAttrs.key + '" placeholder="' + tAttrs.localized + '" ' + required + '   />' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>';

            tElement.replaceWith(html);


        }


    }

});
```

The tag is embedded in a Controller. But if I access the model in the controller via scope, the model is empty.
Moreover the ng-class attribute is not evaluated, i.e. The CSS is not assigned as it should be.

**EDIT** The access to the model does now work. But the ng-class attribute still is not evaluated properly.

Comment: You'll probably benefit from using the [$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile) service.

Comment: What are you expecting from the `ng-class` attribute? Based on the ngClazz variable, it looks like `ng-class` will be an empty string if the `formpath` attribute is present.

Comment: The CSS class of that div should be "error" (used from twitter bootstrap) if the form element is invalid (what it is at the beginning). This mechanism shall be active only when the formpath is set. In the generated HTML the ng-class is set properly. But for some reason the styling is not.

Answer (score 0):

Use $compile. transclude is imho not necessary:

```
app.directive("bootstrapinput", function($compile) {
    return {
       restrict: 'E',
       scope: {
           model: '='
       },
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           var type = attrs.type || 'text';
           var required = attrs.hasOwnProperty('required') ? 'required' : '';
           var ngClazz = attrs.hasOwnProperty('formpath') ? 'ng-class="{error: ' + attrs.formpath + '.$invalid}"' : '';
           var htmlTemplate = '<div class="control-group" ' + ngClazz + '>' + '<label class="control-label" for="' + attrs.key + '">' + attrs.localized + '</label>' + '<div class="controls">' + '<input ng-model="' + attrs.model + '" type="' + type + '" id="' + attrs.key + '" name="' + attrs.key + '" placeholder="' + attrs.localized + '" ' + required + '   />' + '</div>' + '</div>';
           console.log(htmlTemplate);
           var compiled = $compile(htmlTemplate)(scope);

           element.replaceWith(compiled);
       }
   };
});
```

Comment: I've modified my solution based on your proposal: http://jsfiddle.net/b9B8S/3/ The CSS error class still does not work. Moreover I have to leave out the scope: {model:'='} otherwise it does not work

Comment: With compile, most of the styling works good, but the "error" class is still not supplied: http://jsfiddle.net/JNgN2/5/

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally I have the solution

I've just wrapped the div control-group in a further div. Now it works.

```
'<div><div class="control-group" ...>...</div></div>'
```

see also 
http://jsfiddle.net/JNgN2/6/